# name 'File' is not define when used with FASTAPI

Tags: python, fastapi

The following function should output the file size of the image when sending a Post request from Insomnia/Postman API development environments.

```
@app.post("/user/photo")
async def upload_user_photo(response: Response, profile_photo: bytes = File(...)):
    response.headers["x-file-size"] = str(len(profile_photo))
    response.set_cookie(key="cookie-api", value="test")
    return {"file size": len(profile_photo)}
```

However the following error occurs:

```
  File ".\run.py", line 54, in <module>
    async def upload_user_photo(response: Response, profile_photo: bytes = File(...)):
NameError: name 'File' is not defined
```

I've read that File() has been depreciated from Python 3, so what would be a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python `file` function was deprecated.  Remember that capitalization matters.  What that code wants is the `File` class from fastapi.  You need to add:

```
from fastapi import File
```

Comment: Ensure multipart package is also being installed. ```pip install python-multipart```